# editing datagridcell within a DataGridTemplateColumn on key press (key up) event

Tags: wpf, vb.net, datagrid

i have a DataGridTemplateColumn that i created, nothing much

```
 Public Class DataGridAutoCompleteColumn
        Inherits DataGridTemplateColumn

        Protected Overrides Function PrepareCellForEdit(editingElement As FrameworkElement, editingEventArgs As RoutedEventArgs) As Object
            editingElement.MoveFocus(New TraversalRequest(FocusNavigationDirection.First))
            Return MyBase.PrepareCellForEdit(editingElement, editingEventArgs)
        End Function
    End Class
```

i also have an Auto complete control (which works very well)
and i am using it inside this column like this

```
                     <DataGrid.Resources>
                        <DataTemplate x:Key="EditingDateTemplate">
                            <Auto:AutoCompleteTextBox FocusManager.FocusedElement="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}"
                                                      x:Name="EditingBox" 
                                                      Text="{Binding Path=Name,Mode=TwoWay,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"  ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource MyComplList}}"/>                               
                        </DataTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate x:Key="NormalCellDataTemplate">
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Name,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged,FallbackValue=Add New ...}"/>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </DataGrid.Resources>
                    <DataGrid.Columns>
                        <Auto:DataGridAutoCompleteColumn
                            CellTemplate="{StaticResource NormalCellDataTemplate}" 
                            CellEditingTemplate="{StaticResource EditingDateTemplate}" 
                            Header="Test Auto Complete"/>
                    </DataGrid.Columns>
```

the focusing mechanism and every thing works well , but i am facing one problem
"Editing"

When double clicking the cell , it goes into Edit mode BUT when i start typing  without double clicking it doesn't (not like what the DataGridTextColumn does)

so i made a workaround for this in the keyup event within the datagrid

```
 Private Sub MyDataGrid_KeyUp(sender As Object, e As KeyEventArgs)
    Dim ignorablekeys() As Key = {Key.Up, Key.Down, Key.Left, Key.Right, Key.Delete, Key.Return, Key.LeftShift, Key.RightShift, Key.LeftCtrl, Key.RightCtrl, Key.LeftAlt, Key.RightAlt}
    If Not ignorablekeys.Contains(e.Key) Then
        If TypeOf e.OriginalSource Is DataGridCell Then
            Dim cell = DirectCast(e.OriginalSource, DataGridCell)
            If Not cell.IsReadOnly Then
                Dim datagrid = DirectCast(sender, DataGrid)
                datagrid.BeginEdit()
                'Push the entered Text Into the cell <<<<< Problem >>>>>
                 Dim e1 = New KeyEventArgs(e.KeyboardDevice, e.InputSource, e.Timestamp, e.Key)
                 e1.RoutedEvent = KeyUpEvent
                 InputManager.Current.ProcessInput(e1)
            End If
        End If
    End If

End Sub
```

the problem is , it doesn't work , it doesn't send the text

Comment: this question was very old back when i started wpf, the solution here could be to use `PreviewKeyUp` instead of `KeyUp` or something like that, not sure